# jaxb how to exclude objectfactory from generting

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb2

while creating java classes from xsd, it creates ObjectFactory.java which I need to avoid from creation. What is the best way to do that? Since it is created runtime, can't hardcode any path etc in POM.xml. Using maven-jaxb2 plugin.

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <xsd.build.dir>${basedir}/src/main/resources</xsd.build.dir>
        <generated.source.location>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/src</generated.source.location>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateDirectory>${generated.source.location}</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${xsd.build.dir}</schemaDirectory>
                    <episode>true</episode>
                    <addIfExistsToEpisodeSchemaBindings>true</addIfExistsToEpisodeSchemaBindings>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.6.4</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        </build>
</project>
```

Why I want it -> basically I am using below annotation to create complex type and I don't want xjc to create 'test' class but I don't know how to suppress it.
Since it creates test, objectfactory shows error and objectfactory is not needed anyway.

```
<xs:complexType name="test">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:class name="test"
                    implClass="somepackage.test123" />
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: How are you generating the jaxb classes ??

Comment: using the plugin ( which has XJC ) mentioned in the question along with maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: There are hundreds of maven jaxb plugin... Please post your current POM configuration.

Comment: @Dev please post the content of pom.xml in your question. Though I dont think there is option to avoid generation of ObjectFactory class. You can add command to delete it after generation of jaxb classes

Comment: @Dev Why do you care? It's just an unused class, minuscule in size by comparison to everything else, so it really doesn't hurt being there.

Comment: updated the question with more details

Comment: You could instead mark it as *ignored* from the source control ?